# SVG point symbol GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to use SVG symbols created in Inkscape to symbolize a point layer.

I got the first symbol to work, a simple black square. But when I draw an antenna symbol, an X with a circle, it shows up as a grey square.

What could be causing this? Am I using some property in Inkscape which is not compatible with GeoServer?

A log message when searching for the SVG file is:

> 2021-08-04 16:38:42,034 WARN [geotools.styling] - can't parse mast.svg
> as a java resource present in the classpath

[image]

```
..
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <Name>Hus storleksklass 2</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>kkod</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>736</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
            <ExternalGraphic>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="hus.svg" />
              <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
            </ExternalGraphic>
            <Size>7</Size>
            
          </Graphic>
       </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
      
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <Name>Mast</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>kkod</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>373</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
            <ExternalGraphic>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="mast.svg" />
              <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
            </ExternalGraphic>
            <Size>10</Size>
            
          </Graphic>
       </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
...
```

Comment: A grey square is the default symbol when none of the other provided marks or graphics can be drawn. So, check the file is where GeoServer expects it (relative to the `styles` folder) and that the user running GeoServer can read the file, then check the log file for other possible errors like invalid or unexpected SVG

Comment: then you'll need to see what is going wrong in the logs

Comment: You need to turn logging up to see what causes that warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the logging profile to VERBOSE_LOGGING which (I think) gave me the log message:

> The attribute "rx" of the element ellipse is required

Which is the x radius of an ellipse.

I redrew the symbol and made sure I drew a circle instead of an ellipse and the problem was solved:

[image]